# Error while loading .so library inside docker container when running a jar file

Tags: java, docker, .so

I was trying to run a java spring boot application inside a docker container. The jar file (testapp.jar) contains all dependencies, and one of the dependency includes a .so (libjsimplerdma.so) library in it. When I run the image, it throw the following exceptions:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jxio8802823867088/libjsimplerdma.so: libsimplerdma.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My Dockerfile has:

```
FROM centos:7
WORKDIR /
RUN yum update -y \
   && yum -y install gcc glibc glibc-common \
   && yum -y install cmake \
   && yum -y install epel-release \
   && yum -y install python python-pip libxslt-devel python-devel libxml2- devel \
   && yum -y install java \
   && yum -y clean all

COPY testapp.jar /var/lib/test-app/testapp.jar
COPY application.properties /var/lib/test-app/application.properties
ADD run-test-app.sh /

USER root
ENTRYPOINT ["/run-test-app.sh"]
```

And inside run-test-app.sh, I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting testapp"
cd /var/lib/test-app
java -Djava.library.path=/tmp/ -jar testapp.jar -- spring.config.location=/var/lib/test-app/
```

The testapp.jar includes jtest-rdma.jar which contains libjsimplerdma.so file:

In testapp.jar:

```
38713 Wed Feb 27 11:55:10 EST 2019 BOOT-INF/lib/jtest-rdma.jar
```

And jtest-rdma.jar has libjsimplerdma.so:

```
19024 Wed Feb 27 11:55:10 EST 2019 libjsimplerdma.so
```

When I run the image with docker, I got the following errors:

```
Native code library failed to load
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jxio8802823867088/libjsimplerdma.so: libsimplerdma.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And when I check the `/tmp`, I only see a directory `jxio8802823867088` created, but no file inside.

If I run the jar locally (without docker container), it is working fine.

I'm not sure what I missed here?

Comment: Do you have a custom loader to load the .so from the .jar? Otherwise, I would expect the .so would need to be at the specified .library.path.

Comment: The same jar works locally without docker container.

Comment: @YHC, I have the same issue, did you manage to fix it?